# Some anchor tags not working in IE < 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer

There are several anchor tags in my site that fail to work on IE 9 or lower. They work just fine on IE 10+ and any other browser, just not IE 9.

Any example of an anchor tag that does work:

```
<a href="contact.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>Contact</span></a>
```

Whereas something like the one below doesn't work:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/username">Twitter</a>
```

I figured it might have to do with CSS selectors, but even with those removed, the upper one does function, while the lower one doesn't.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your situation?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is it not clickable? That can be caused by another DOM element sitting on top of the link making it unclickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

The anchor tags were sitting inside of a div that had a pseudo-class applied to it.

```
content: '';
```

Removing that made the links clickable again. However, this obviously canceled out the effect.

Comment: The [CSS content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) is CSS2 and should be supported in IE8+. Perhaps you are using the [CSS3 syntax vs. the CSS2 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after), if so I'd suggest going to CSS2 syntax to support IE8.

Comment: Please share your code; did you have a pseudo element over the top of your anchors, preventing clicks from reaching the link?